# Coordinate mismatch.Is there any way to find out the corresponding coordinate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, coordinates, postgis, geojson

I am new in postgreSQL. I have imported one table in my postgreSQL database. Imported table has a 'geom' field(coordinates in form of encrypted). while i am using below query

```
select ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from dataTab where objectid='3'
```

I am getting coordinates as below

```
"{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[979999.082000002,196493.280000001],[979897.966399997,196147.8204],[979718.105800003,196197.441599995],[979823.056799993,196549.6884],[979999.082000002,196493.280000001]]]]}"
```

But for me to draw this data to map I need to get the coordinates as the form below

`[-73.9284914226121,40.5578463559797]` -- this coordinates in google map having WK id is 4326

Anybody please help me to get this please..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to say that I got the answer for above question.

First we need to find out the SRID of our table. For that use below code

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM dataTab LIMIT 1;
```

If it is ‘0’ it's ok there is no problem.
 In my case the WELL-KNOWN IDENTIFIER for my table is 2263.

To get geom data corresponding to WELL-KNOWN IDENTIFIER 4326 please run the below query

```
select st_asgeojson(st_transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 2263), 4326)) AS geojson 
FROM  dataTab 
where objectid='3'
```

Result of above query is

```
"{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-74.0153321127314,40.706004363516],[-74.0156965908607,40.7050561091758],[-74.0163453320659,40.7051922173924],[-74.0159670334229,40.7061591049526],[-74.0153321127314,40.706004363516]]]]}"
```